# Zipping files two by two

Tags: bash, command-line, wildcards, zip

I have a directory that has 800 files like this:

```
file1.png
file1@2x.png

file2.png
file2@2x.png

file3.png
file3@2x.png

... etc
```

I need to create zip files like this

```
file1.zip (containing file1.png and file1@2x.png)
file2.zip (containing file2.png and file2@2x.png)
file3.zip (containing file3.png and file3@2x.png)
```

Is there a magic command I can use to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If [always there are two](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_of_Two), is simple:

```
for f in file+([0-9]).png; do zip "${f%png}zip" "$f" "${f/./@2x.}"; done
```

Note that the above will work as is from the command line. If you intend to use it in a script, put `shopt -s extglob` somewhere before that line. (`extglob` is enabled by default only in interactive shells.)

In old `bash` not handling extended patterns this ugly workaround will work, but better change the logic [as suggested in another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56218) by Leonid:

```
for f in file[0-9].png file*[0-9][0-9].png; do zip "${f%png}zip" "$f" "${f/./@2x.}"; done
```

Comment: I am receiving this error after trying your command... -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: I am trying it from command line and seeing this error

Comment: Which `bash` version you use? Mine is 4.2.37.

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)... this is mountain lion OSX

Comment: I added this line of yours to a script, and it works partially. Only the regular file is included in the zip, not the @2x...

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  THANKS!!!!!!!!!

Comment: `extglob` is not enabled by default in interactive shells, but maybe your OS ships with a `bashrc` that turns it on (and extglob has been added to bash in 2.02-alpha1)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, none of my rc files contain `extglob` setting. `extglob` defaults to what `bash` `configure`'s `--enable-extended-glob-default` switch indicated. And that switch is “enabled by default, unless the operating system does not provide the necessary support”. This may be the difference between Linux and OSX behavior.

Comment: No, `--enable-extended` is enabled by default (`opt_extended_glob=yes` in `configre`), but not `--enable-extended-glob-default` (`opt_extglob_default=no`), that's an inaccuracy in the documentation. It must have been explicitly enabled by your OS maintainer. But point taken about different bash distributions having different defauts.

Comment: Thank you @StephaneChazelas, I will investigate on this.

Answer (score 4):

How about a slightly modified version of what was suggested by manatwork? Something like this:
`for f in file*@2x.png; do zip ${f%@2x.png}.zip $f ${f/@2x./.}; done`

It iterates over the 'second in pair' files only, and there's no regexp in the file list generation.