# zipping files iteratively

Tags: bash, shell, filenames, archive

I have a folder with 77K PDFs(~500 GB in size). I want to zip them into 77 zipped files, each containing 1000 PDFs, so that they are easier to upload and share with peers. I don't know how to write for loops in bash and use the zip commands there, but I saw some examples in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56212/zipping-files-two-by-two) question. Can someone help me out here?

The filenames go like this :

```
FinalRoll_MR_ACNo_@PartNo_%%.pdf
```

The @ and %% are numbers. If I can zip the first 1000 files in a file like archive_1.tar.gz and so on, then it'd be great! If we can retain the order of files in alphabetical order, then it'll be even better!

I am using an AWS ec2 instance that's running Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say "zip" (which is an available utility), but then show a sample output filename of .tar.gz, which implies a gzipped tar file. Which would you like?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for pointing that out! I didn’t have any particular zipping format in mind while writing the question and any format will work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use List::MoreUtils qw(natatime);
use Sort::Naturally;

# specify directory on command line, or default to .
my $dir = shift || '.';

# Find all the PDF files. 
#
# NOTE: you could use perl's `Find::File` module instead of
# readdir() to do a recursive search like `find`.
opendir(DIR, $dir) || die "Can't open $dir: $!\n";
my @pdfs = nsort grep { /\.pdf$/i && -f "$dir/$_" } readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

my $size=1000;

my $i=1;
my $iter = natatime $size, @pdfs;
while( my @tmp = $iter->() ){
  my $tarfile="archive_" . sprintf('%02i',$i++) . ".tar.gz";
  #print join(" ", ('tar','cfz',$tarfile, @tmp)),"\n";
  system('echo','tar','cfz',$tarfile, @tmp);
}
```

This uses the `natatime()` ("n-at-a-time") function in perl's `List::MoreUtils` library module to iterate over the list of PDF files 1000 at a time.

It also uses the `Sort::Naturally` module to natural-sort the PDF filenames.  Drop that (and the call to `nsort` on the `my @pdfs = ...` line) if you don't need or want that.

The tar filenames have 2-digit zero-padded numbers in them so that they sort correctly. Change it to 3 or more digits if you have enough PDF files to fill more than 99 tar archives.

The code, as written, is a **dry-run**.  Delete the `'echo',` from the `system()` function call to make it actually tar up the batches of PDF files.

For verbose output while running without `echo`, uncomment the `print` statement. BTW, it would be easy to make it print a timestamp, e.g. seconds since the epoch with the perl built-in `time()`, or nicely formatted with the `Date::Format` module. e.g:

```
print join(" ", (time(),'tar','cfz',$tarfile, @tmp)),"\n";
```

Save as, e.g., `vibhu.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x vibhu.pl`.  Here's a sample run (in a directory with only 10 ".pdf" files):

```
$ touch {1..10}.pdf
$ ./vibhu.pl 
tar cfz archive_01.tar.gz 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf 4.pdf 5.pdf 6.pdf 7.pdf 8.pdf 9.pdf 10.pdf
```

If you change `$size=1000` to, e.g., `$size=3`, you can see that it is actually doing N at a time pdf files:

```
$ ./vibhu.pl 
tar cfz archive_01.tar.gz 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf
tar cfz archive_02.tar.gz 4.pdf 5.pdf 6.pdf
tar cfz archive_03.tar.gz 7.pdf 8.pdf 9.pdf
tar cfz archive_04.tar.gz 10.pdf
```

---

The [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/release/List-MoreUtils) and [Sort::Naturally](https://metacpan.org/release/Sort-Naturally) modules are available from [CPAN](https://www.cpan.org/).  They may already be packaged for your distribution.  e.g. on Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install liblist-moreutils-perl libsort-naturally-perl
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the bash shell, you could put the filenames into an array (sorting naturally with the wildcard expansion), then slice out 1000 at a time in an indexed loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

filenames=( *.pdf )
for((index=1; index <= $(( (${#filenames[@]} / 1000) + 1)); index++))
do
  start=$(( (index-1) * 1000 ))
  tar czf archive"${index}".tar "${filenames[@]:start:999}"
done
```

The `for` loop runs as many times as is needed to get 1000 files per run. The `start` variable indicates where the array slice should start. The `tar` command creates an indexed tar file of the 1000 files in the array starting at `start` through the next 999 files (or as many as are left, at the end).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk scripts to create shell script. Review compress.sh and then execute it:

```
ls *.pdf | awk 'BEGIN {ORS=""; print "#!/bin/sh"; } NR%1000 == 1 {  print "\nzip Archive_" NR ".zip"; } { print " \\\n" $0; }' > compress.sh
```

Comment: “Review compress.sh and then execute” What is this .sh file?

Comment: The file generated with awk script

Comment: Oh I get it! > outputs a list of commands in the .sh file! Very clever

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: In this case filenames does not contain neither newlines nor spaces, nor quotes, so it's OK

Comment: it's **never** OK.  it's a bad habit that should not be indulged.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative with find and xargs, because you shouldn't parse `ls`:

```bash
export numfile="$(mktemp)"
echo 0 > "$numfile"

find lots_of_files/ -name '*.pdf' -print0 \
| sort -V -z \
| xargs -0r -L 1000  \
bash -c 'NUM=$(cat "$numfile") ; ((NUM++)); echo "$NUM" > "$numfile"; \
  tar -czf archive_$(printf '%03d' "$NUM" ).tar.gz "$@"' tar_in_batches

rm "$numfile"
unset numfile
```

You'll get your archives nicely numbered with leading zeroes and the files within the archives will be in the right order, too.

This version won't break if there are spaces or newlines in your filenames.

Comment: nice idea.  the `find -print0` and `xargs -0` are good, but piping the output of xargs into `while read` like that undoes the good work of NUL-separating the filenames.   maybe run a script or `sh -c '...'` from xargs instead (script would have to use a tmpfile or something to maintain state for the NUM counter).

Comment: @cas Good catch!  I'll have to think about that...

Comment: something like `numfile="$(mktemp)"; echo 0 > "$numfile"; find ... -print0 | sort -V -Z | xargs -0r -L 1000 sh -c 'NUM=$(cat "$1") ; ((NUM++)); echo "$NUM" > "$1"; shift; tar ... "$@"' sh "$numfile"; rm "$numfile"` would do it.

Comment: @cas Updated as per your suggestion.  We need `bash`, though, `sh` didn't want to do `((NUM++))`.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 but that won't work quite right. you'll be losing the first filename argument because you haven't provided a name as the zeroth argument to `bash -c`.   should be `bash -c '...' arbitrary_name "$@"`.   also, if you're going to export numfile, you should `unset` it when you no longer need it....that's why I had it as $1 for the script, to avoid the need for export & unset.

Comment: i meant `bash -c '...' arbitrary_name`, without the `"$@"` on the end - didn't notice the error in time.

Comment: e.g. running your script (edited to put echo before the tar) results in `tar -czf archive_001.tar.gz ./2.pdf ./3.pdf ./4.pdf ./5.pdf ./6.pdf ./7.pdf ./8.pdf ./9.pdf ./10.pdf`.   **Notice the missing `1.pdf`.**  Running it with **any** word after the final `'` of the bash script results in `tar -czf archive_001.tar.gz ./1.pdf ./2.pdf ./3.pdf ./4.pdf ./5.pdf ./6.pdf ./7.pdf ./8.pdf ./9.pdf ./10.pdf`

Comment: I used `The_Tarinator` as the arbitrary process name, and that's how it would show up in `ps`, `pgrep`, etc.   e.g.   `bash -c '....... tar -czf archive_$(printf '%03d' "$NUM" ).tar.gz "$@"' The_Tarinator`

Comment: And I was wondering...  Note to self: give bash -c a name.  Updated. Thanks again!